# Why does backupd cause excessive (tens of GB) swap memory usage when doing a Time Machine backup?

Tags: time-machine, virtual-memory

My MBP has only 8GB RAM, and whenever it does an hourly Time Machine backup it starts to crawl. This causes the backup to take a very long time for not much data.

At this point, Swap Memory usage is up to 12GB which is way above my usual/everyday Swap Memory usage of < 2GB.

Once the backup is over half way through, Swap Memory usage is at roughly 5GB until it is finished when it drops back to normal.

Is it usual for backupd to need so much memory?

> [TheTimeMachineMechanic](https://eclecticlight.co/downloads/) gave this diagnostic, 
>   confirming that 878MB took 35 minutes!
>
> ```
> Analysis from 2019-01-30 12:23:58 +0000 to 2019-01-30 14:23:58 +0000 for 2 hours:
> Backing up to /dev/disk2s2: /Volumes/Tardis/Backups.backupdb
> on which there were 228.35 GB available.
> Started 1 auto backups, and 0 manual backups; completed 1 backups successfully,
> last backup completed successfully 7.0 minutes ago,
> backed up a total of 7193 files, range 1884 to 5309 in each backup,
> total data for each backup was 335.4 MB, 878.3 MB.
> Times taken for each auto backup were 34.9 minutes,
> Created 1 new backups, and deleted 0 old backups,
> Created 2 new snapshots, and deleted 0 old snapshots,
> cancelled 2 backups.
> No error messages found.
> ```

My system:

- MacBook Pro (Retina, 13-inch, Early 2013)
- 3 GHz Intel Core i7
- 8 GB 1600 MHz DDR3
- LaCie Rugged 1TB Thunderbolt drive

Edit: April 2019

Usually my Mac is at somewhere less than 2GB of swap memory, but during a Time Machine backup it balloons to ~20GB, throttled - I imagine - only by the free space on my drive (~30GB).

My computer slows to a crawl and is unusable until the backup either completes or fails. The screenshot shows a backup of only 250MB!

During all of this, there is no one process that is running away with memory.

So, what's going on? And how can I avoid this?

[image]

Comment: Going to take some spelunking to dig into your memory usage. Are you able to reproduce this if you make a brand new user account that starts nothing - disable auto log in and reboot - start with the clean user and run Time Machine? My thinking is it's the other things you have running and not TM that results in the balloon. Of course TM pushes your system into swap, but it's probably not the "cause" is my thinking.

Comment: I'll try that. Somebody on Twitter suggested it could be the complexity of my existing backup data, that causes TM/macOS to struggle working with all those aliases. So I'll also see if I can find a spare drive to try a fresh backup to a blank disc on my account.

Comment: Just have not had time to do anything about this (so only backing up once a week).

Comment: @bmike I recently cleared out a load of old files on my Mac and went from ~5% free space to >15% free space and this issue seems to have gone away (a couple of days regular hourly backups so far). The CPU still works hard and fans come on, but swap memory never reaches silly levels. This all makes no sense, so I'll wait a while longer to confirm.

Comment: @bmike false alarm, it's still doing it, sometimes. gah this is annoying.

Comment: Finally upgraded to a new Mac and zero'd my backup. Should get another decade before this happens again.

Comment: This is happening again but the new Mac is sufficiently fast to make it much less noticeable.